# Conformal mapping example

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to find how the conformal map $C(w)=w^2$ maps the domain $r\exp(i\phi)$ (with $r>0$ and $0\leq \phi \leq \pi$). Can someone show me how this is done?

Comment: What do you mean by "the conformal map of a map"?

Comment: @mrf Thanks, I edited the question. Should make more sense now (hopefully)

Answer (score 1):

If $z = re^{i\phi}$, then $z^2 = r^2e^{2i\phi}$. How will $r^2$ and $2\phi$ vary when you let $r$ and $\phi$ vary as stated? (By the way, it makes more sense to have $0 < \phi < \pi$, since that gives you an open domain.)

Comment: Ah, I see. So it just turns it into a circle all together